# How can I apply clustering by condition in python

Tags: python, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have a dataset about 50 000 samples and it contains 2 features where the first is binary and the second is continual.

I would like to use python for using the clustering method in order to create 2 categories.

**PS**: I couldn't specify when the first category is limited exactly to make rules. I need to have a category with most numbers = 0, i.e my goal is that in my data there is a part that I must eliminate it. It has the majority of col_A value are 0 I need to remove them but I don't know where they limited

My data look like:

```
id        Col_A       Col_B
1           0           2
2           0           3
3           1          25 
4           0          17
5           0           9
6           1          30
7           1           1
8           1          12
9           1           3
10          0           6
```

I would like to get 2 clusters

- the first category is about rows that contain small numbers and the majority of Col_A values are 0.
- and the second category should contain bigger numbers regardless of Col_A values.

**Category 1 must have:**

```
id        Col_A       Col_B     
1           0           2
2           0           3
5           0           9
7           1           1
9           1           3
10          0           6
```

and **category 2 must have:**

```
id        Col_A       Col_B    
3           1          25 
4           0          17
6           1          30
8           1          12
```

How can I impose to the clustering algorithm that the first category must have a majority of 0 numbers as values of Col_A

I have used the following code but it doesn't work perfectly.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 25],[0, 17], [0, 9], [1, 30], [1, 1],[1, 12], [1, 3], [0, 6]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(data)
kmeans.labels_

df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df['categories'] = kmeans.labels_
```

I gat some problemes like in case of "18" that must be categorised on category 2.

```
Col_A      Col_B        Category
0            2           Cat_1
0            3           Cat_1
1           12           Cat_2
0           17           Cat_2
0            9           Cat_1
1           30           Cat_2
1            1           Cat_1
1           18           Cat_1
0            3           Cat_1
0            6           Cat_1
```

Whene I work on my real data i.e with massive sample I get wrong classification. how Can  I  fix this situation

Comment: Kmeans is an unsupervised algorithm, which in layman terms means that it will cluster data according to some pattern it will find in data. In your case you know how to cluster the data, y apply K means, just write rules and get done with it!!

Comment: How do you define the boundary between small/big numbers? What if the smallest number that allows the separation to have majority 0's, is a "large" number?

Comment: I couldn't specify when the first category is limited exactly to make rules. I need to have a category with most numbers = 0, i.e in my data there is a part that I must eliminate it that have the majority of col_A value are 0 I need to remove them but I dont know where they limited

Comment: Couldn't you just greedily iterate starting with a boundary value of 1, then 2, 3... and see if gives a split that fits your requirements? I think you need to define your problem in more detail. Machine-learning algorithms typically _approximate_, they dont guarantee much other than their validation accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if your clustering depends on column B and you know what the boundary is, then it sounds like there is no need for unsupervised algorithm and you could assign label 0 if column_ B < boundary and label 1 if column_B > boundary.

If you still want to use an unsupervised clustering algorithm, try re-scaling your columns. Instead of standardising the columns (the usual approach), which gives all the columns the same 'importance' in the algorithm, multiply all numbers in column B by some factor (let's say by 10), and cluster again. This will make column B more 'important'.

Comment: should I multiply each col_B in the same number?

Comment: but I need to focus more on the first column where the first category must have the majority of numbers are 0.

Comment: I don't think an unsupervised algorithm will be useful in this case. 

It sounds like a better option would be to manually label part of your dataset and then use a neural network to learn the rules.

Comment: unfortunately! I steel beginner in machine learning and I have never learned about neural network. Can you help me how to make python source code by using a neural network for solving this problem or suggest to me what should I read exactly for getting the solution

Answer (score 0):

Kmeans is an unsupervised learning algorithm which wouldn't guarantee finding a global optimum.

Why not use pandas and assign groups by conditions for this case.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[df.column2 > x]
df2 = df[df.column2 <= x]
```

Comment: I couldn't specify when the first category is limited exactly to make rules. I need to have a category with most numbers = 0, i.e in my data there is a part that I must eliminate it that have the majority of col_A value are 0 I need to remove them but I dont know where they limited